# How to pass variables to strapi graphql api?

Tags: graphql, next.js, strapi

I have the following graphql code in my strapi and nextjs project. The code is working in the graphql end point playground but some how it keeps getting error in my local environment showing  `message: 'Syntax Error: Expected Name, found <EOF>.',` when I try to fetch data from nextjs. I have ready this [strapi documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/graphql-api.html#create-a-new-entry) but cant seems to find anything relevant with my current issues. Any can please tell me what error I am making here?

```
export async function getPostAndMorePosts(slug, preview) {
  const data = await fetchAPI(
    `
    fragment FileParts on UploadFileEntityResponse {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          alternativeText
          width
          height
          mime
          url
          formats
        }
      }
    }
query Posts($slug: String!) {
  posts(filters: {slug: {eq: $slug}})  {
    data{
      attributes{
        title
        content
        
        excerpt
        slug
        category{
          data{
            attributes{
              name
            }
          }
        }

        coverImage{
          ...FileParts

        }
        
      }
    }
  
}
  
  
  morePost: posts(filters: {slug: {ne: $slug}},pagination: { start: 0, limit: 4 })  {
    data{
      attributes{
        title
        content
        
        excerpt
        slug
        category{
          data{
            attributes{
              name
            }
          }
        }

        coverImage{
          ...FileParts

        }
        publishedAt
        
      }
    }
  
  }
}`,
    {variables:{
    
          slug:slug
        }
      }
  )
  return data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a closing bracket which is misaligned at the moment! Look at the code below

```
export async function getPostAndMorePosts(slug, preview) {
    const data = await fetchAPI(
      `
      fragment FileParts on UploadFileEntityResponse {
        data {
          id
          attributes {
            alternativeText
            width
            height
            mime
            url
            formats
          }
        }
      }
    } -> closed here
  query Posts($slug: String!) {
    posts(filters: {slug: {eq: $slug}})  {
      data{
        attributes{
          title
          content
          
          excerpt
          slug
          category{
            data{
              attributes{
                name
              }
            }
          }
  
          coverImage{
            ...FileParts
  
          }
          
        }
      }
    
  }
    
    
    morePost: posts(filters: {slug: {ne: $slug}},pagination: { start: 0, limit: 4 })  {
      data{
        attributes{
          title
          content
          
          excerpt
          slug
          category{
            data{
              attributes{
                name
              }
            }
          }
  
          coverImage{
            ...FileParts
  
          }
          publishedAt
          
        }
      }
    
    }
  `, -> removed from here
      {variables:{
      
            slug:slug
          }
        }
    )
    return data
  }
```

So it's just an issue of {} alligment.